# Jquery Date Picker get current date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I get the current `datepicker` date format?

[Here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) you can find the Jquery UI Date Picker plugin.

*Note:* I had search a lot but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: plugin link ???

Comment: is it the jquery ui one ?

Comment: I made a edit with the plugin

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/12347/)

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('option', 'dateFormat'));
```

Comment: this is not working in my case.

Comment: 2min i create a jsfiddle

Comment: This was not working for other reason. Now it is working. I will accept your answer even this post is duplicated.

Comment: happy i helped :D